# How do you test the SwiftUI views?

Tags: ios, swiftui

I am building a SwiftUI application to manage movies. I am using MVVM approach for SwiftUI and I ended up with the following unit test for my View model to verify that the validation is working and the message is displayed on the screen, when the TextField is empty. I wrote the following test.

```
   func testExample() throws {
            
            let vm = AddMovieViewModel()
            vm.title = ""
            vm.year = ""
            vm.addMovie()
           
            XCTAssertEqual(vm.message, "Error occurred.")
        }
```

But I have a feeling that this test is not doing much and it is testing the implementation details instead of the behavior. If I refactor the addMovie to saveMovie without changing the implementation then the test will fail. Even though the behavior has not changed.

For SwiftUI, how do you test the UI? Few options I have heard are

- Manual testing using Xcode Previews
- ViewInspector
- E2E Testing to test the complete story instead of just the behavior.

Thoughts!

Comment: This is a unit test not a ui test. Look into UI tests you can record steps and add tests throughout.

Comment: Is there any point of these unit tests? The VM is checking whether a property is set correctly or not. That property "message" is responsible for displaying data on the view. Would it not be better to write a UI Test using View Inspector or to check this manually.

Comment: In a properly architectured app the unit tests are where most of the time is spent, where you find the most bugs. There are plenty of tutorials about the differences an value of each.

Comment: The problem with MVVM is they use @StateObject when they don't need a reference type...for some weird reason.